# How to configure a default domain option for the cookies setter method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

In Ruby on Rails, it is possible to configure sharing the [session cookie](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html) across multiple domains. For example in an initializer like this:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
  key: '_your_app_session', domain: %w[a.example.tld b.example.tld]
```

At it is possible setting a domain option when setting a [single cookie value](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html):

```
cookies[:key] = { value: 'value', domain: %w[a.example.tld b.example.tld] }
```

But it is quite annoying using this verbose syntax each time you want to set a cookie value in the application.

I wasn't able to find any configuration or work-around to set a default domain for all cookies setter calls in the application. What I try to achieve is that I only need to configure default cookie options once and then these defaults are applied whenever I set a cookie value. For example like this:

```
Rails.application.config.cookie_defaults = { domain: %w[a.example.tld b.example.tld] }
cookie[:key] = 'value' # has `domain` set as expected without explicitly passed in
```

Is that possible in Ruby on Rails without writing a custom cookie setter method?

Comment: I cannot find anything in the source code that would allow for this; however it does appear that [`CookieJar#[]=`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L367) calls the private method [`#handle_options`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.0/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb#L445) before setting the cookie so you could prepend a module and hook into this, using something as simple as `Hash#merge` without having to redefine the cookie setter method.

Comment: That being said it would be fragile given the fact that it relies on private internal implementation